# How to handle the dtmf in linphone

Tags: linphone

I want to send DTMF to orange pi, I know that I can handle DTMF using log file, but i cant find it. How can i set the file path obviously?
I can't find any answers in the net. to this question. I use console version of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is a bit late, however I am struggling with linphone too. I trying the same thing like you.
You can specify your output file, while starting linphonecsh.

Try:
`linphonecsh init -a -c ~/.linphonerc -d 6 -l /temp/log.txt`

- [-a]         -> enable auto answering for incoming calls
- [-c]   -> specify path of configuration file
- [-d] <0...6> -> in range 0 to 6 you can specify the output level (recommend 5 or 6)

Once you have done this, you need to change in the config file the attribute "use_info" to 1.

- 0 = don't use sip-info messages for DTMFs.
- 1 = use use sip-info messages for DTMFs.

I got the inforamtion in those links:

- http://write.flossmanuals.net/linphone/configuring/
- https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Linphone/Linphone%20and%20Raspberry%20Pi/

I hope it is not to late and my answer helped you out!